# log from static method using Log4j2

Tags: java, osgi, log4j2

I'm trying to use Log4j2 in an OSGi environment. I've got it to work so far, but while inspecting the logs from the console and from the file, I noticed that some of them were missing, specifically logs that were called from a static method.
The `Log` class in the example below is just a convenience class to let my colleagues call the logging functionality more easily (in the example for just a `String` it seems like overkill of course) through a create method. It does nothing more than create an instance of the Log class that has a `Logger` internally that calls the respective method from the Log4j2 logger.

My question is: Do I just have a simple error in my project or is Log4j2 **not** able to log to files from static methods?

Here's a code example to make it a bit more clear:

```
Log log = Log.testLog();
    log.info("non static log" );
```

That's the code I call from a non-static method.
And here's the `testLog()`-method:

```
public static Log testLog() {
    Log.create( Log.class ).info( "static log" );
    return Log.create( Log.class );
}
```

Results:
Both `#info()` calls write to the Console Appender, but **only** the "non static log" message is written to the file.

Here's my `log4j2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>


<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console">
        <PatternLayout pattern="!ENTRY %logger{1.} %level %d{DEFAULT} [%t]%n!MESSAGE %msg%n%n"/>
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${sys:osgi.logfile}.log4j.log"
            filePattern="${sys:osgi.logfile}.log4j_bak_%i.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <pattern>!ENTRY %logger{1.} %level %d{DEFAULT} [%t]\n!MESSAGE %msg%n%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"
            fileIndex="min"/>
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="TRACE" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Why don't you just call `Log.create( Log.class )` once?

Comment: Would that change something? There's really not a reason behind it, I just quickly slapped the method together for test-purposes.

Comment: I'm not sure but I could imagine that recreating the `Log` instance might clear the buffer. Besides that we normally use a wrapper around log4j such as slf4j or commons logging and thus use a factory to create the loggers but AFAIK log4j provides something similar, probably for exactly the same reason, i.e. you should create a certain logger only once and then reuse that instance.

Comment: Could that factory (or the similar construct from log4j2) be the `LogManager`? If so, that's the construct my `Log` class is using at its core.

Comment: As I said I'm no log4j expert but it sounds like that. In this case you probably should post the relevant parts of `Log.create()`.

Comment: What do you mean "some of them were missing"? Do you mean that location information was missing or that log statements were missing from the log file?

Comment: I mean that log statements were missing from the log file, but were showing in the console.

Comment: After some time trying to solve it I think I can safely say that the problem is not the static method(s). I'm having trouble narrowing it down, but my problem seems to be just in one plugin in the project. (so, I'm not getting any file-logs from that plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the source of my particular problem, which is OSGi (in this case the Equinox Framework). My application uses the `osgi.logfile` system property to point to the location where the logs should be saved at.

Unfortunately Equinox not only creates that property, but also changes it at startup to a different location. For Log4j2 I used `${sys:osgi.logfile}` to get this system property, but because a few particular plugins started so early, Log4j2 still had the wrong (aka. old) location configured for these plugins (more specifically: their `LoggerContext`).

What helped me in this case was a simple `LoggerContext.reconfigure()` on the `LoggerContext` that still had the old location.